# How to pipe indirect output to a file

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

I am calling a process and want to direct all resulting output to a file.  However, the process I'm calling calls a separate process that prints some output to the console.  This output still goes to the console, rather than to my file.

How do I pipe it ALL to a file?

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you are capturing both stdout and stderr. For example if running commands from a bash like shell:

> your_command > your_file.log 2>&1

The order of the two redirection steps is important, you must first send stdout to your_file.log, the 2nd part sends stderr to stdout.

If this doesn't work for you, a little more information about the environment, like what shell you're using would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries this:

```
%promp>./your_exec > your_file.log
```